Airflow metrics not showing in datadog
I don't see any logs coming to the datadog for airflow, I enabled the logs and even added the DD_DOGSTATSD_MAPPER_PROFILES in the helm values for agent. I am looking to send the job logs aswell, which I don't see coming either. Am I missing something in the below config
I do see server and container level metrics are coming like deployment cpu usage and all.
Below are the annotations and metrics I enabled in airflow helm
 metrics:
   statsd_on: true
   statsd_port: 8125
   statsd_prefix: airflow
 webserver:
   base_url: 'https://internal-my-app.com/my-airflow'
   enable_proxy_fix: 'True'
   rbac: 'True'
  annotations:
    ad.datadoghq.com/my-airflow.check_names: '["airflow"]'
    ad.datadoghq.com/my-airflow.init_configs: '[{}]'
    ad.datadoghq.com/my-airflow.instances: |
      [
        {
          "url": "%%host%%/my-airflow:8080"
        }
      ]


